# tikz shift coordinate rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I cannot understand why, in the following example, the first coordinates of the rectangle is correctly shifted and not the second one.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)+(1,2) rectangle (4,4)+(-1,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I see in other posts that I can use '`calc`' library, which is working fine for me.

Thanks

Comment: Does this produce your desired result? `\draw (0,0)+(1,2) rectangle {(4,4)+(-1,-2)};`

Comment: I haven't seen that it also produces an error...

Comment: Please provide absolute coordinate where the rectangle you like to have. Between `(1,2)` and `(3,2)`, i.e. actually it is line, not square?

Comment: You are right Zarko, but my problem is that I saw a rectangle and not a line, but now I understand with the answer of @Heiko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After

```
\draw (0, 0) + (1, 2)
```

the starting point of the rectangle is `(1, 2)` as expected.
Then

```
rectangle (4, 4)
```

draws the rectangle with end point `(4, 4)`.
The remaining stuff

```
+(-1, -2);
```

moves to the point `(3, 2)`, but the movement is not visible.

A point can be given options in square brackets, where a `shift` can be specified:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) +(1, 2) rectangle ([shift={(-1, -2)}] 4, 4);
  \fill[radius=2pt, red] (0, 0) circle[] (4, 4) circle[] ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The rectangle is now a line:

```
\draw (1, 2) rectangle (3, 2);
```

Comment: thanks heiko, I now understand better. It solved my problem